# Unknown Codec with Windows7 Media Center TV recordings

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-media-center, codec

I recently upgraded to Windows7 and I've found myself unable to watch recorded or live TV on Windows Media Center. The video quality is fine, but the audio is just an awfull synthetic sound - just to clarify, this is not poor audio but rather pure noise.

I find however that I'm able to play .avi files w/o issue. I'm not even sure how to go about solving this problem. Ideas?

Here are the stats of my setup:

- Win7 64 bit, fresh repave, not an upgrade
- Hauppuage WinTV HVR-1800
- Over-the-air HD signal

I used gshow, and I get the following details

Partial Render Failure: The following is the error reported by DirectShow

0x00040242 [Unknown]

(Src)->>-(A)->[Decrypt/Tag]>-(B)->[AC3Filter]>-(C)->[Default DirectSound Device]

Update2:

[I've uploaded a sample clip](http://cid-552753bb951aae20.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/BadAudioClip.wtv)

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, but I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the audio codecs Windows 7 comes with. I hear they're not very good quality.

Comment: It's not poor audio but rather pure noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [K-Lite Codec Pack 64-bit](http://www.codecguide.com/klcp_64bit.htm).

> This is a bundle of 64-bit DirectShow
>   filters that can be used together with
>   64-bit players, such as Vista Media
>   Center. This pack can co-exist without
>   problems with the regular (32-bit)
>   K-Lite Codec Pack.

**EDIT**

We were going about it backwards. The article [Win7x64 Components 2.1.8](http://www.brothersoft.com/win7x64-components-234399.html) states:

> 2 versions of Windows Media Player
>   exist on x64 systems. There is a 32bit
>   version stored in \Program Files
>   (x86)\ and a 64bit version stored in
>   \Program Files\
>
> x64 Windows uses the 32bit player as
>   the system default. The installed
>   components of this release include
>   shortcuts to allow you to change the
>   system's default player from the 32bit
>   to 64bit player.
>
> One other Aspect of Windows Media
>   Player(s) on x64 systems needs to be
>   mentioned. If you associate a
>   particular filetype to Open With WMP
>   while the system default is set to use
>   the 64bit player, that filetype will
>   always open the 64bit player when
>   double-clicked. This occurs even if
>   you change the system default back to
>   using the 32bit player.

According to the above, you should actually install the 32-bits codecs.
I would try the new beta version of [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/klcp_beta.htm) 32bits, updated with Win7 features.

If still having troubles, you might install the above `Win7x64 Components` and see what it does in giving you more control.

**EDIT2**

To find the codec of a file, drop it into one of: [GSpot](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/GSpot.htm) or [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) (Tools / Media Information).

**EDIT3**

I found this [thread](http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/p/60276/288111.aspx#288111), which recommends using the [Vista Media Center Decoder Utility](http://mediacenterexpert.blogspot.com/2006/07/vista-media-center-decoder-utility.html):

> This utility will show you the current default decoders, 
>   let you select an alternative from a list of installed decoders 
>   and by pressing Set Default change the defaults

Others counsel the use of [nVIDIA PureVideo Decoder](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/nvidia_purevideo_decoder.htm) or uninstalling FFDSHOW.

Comment: This didn't work

Comment: I tried both options. No luck. That said, not sure I'm using the right settings.

Comment: GSpot 2.70a is supposed to work on 64-bits. You might give it a go and find out which codecs it thinks you're using for audio.

Comment: I get the following info - Partial Render Failure: The following is the error reported by DirectShow
0x00040242 [Unknown]
(Src)->>-(A)->[Decrypt/Tag]>-(B)->[AC3Filter]>-(C)->[Default DirectSound Device]

Not sure what to do with that info

Comment: 0x00040242 means "Some of the streams in this movie are in an unsupported format". So you're missing a codec. Any way for you to post some such file?

Comment: @harrymc - Uploaded to 
http://cid-552753bb951aae20.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/BadAudioClip.wtv

How do I determine which codec I'm missing?

Comment: I've edited-in 2 ways to identify codecs.

Comment: If you have a sample video file, launch the application and drop into its window the file from Windows Explorer.

Comment: So in GSpot the audio codec section is blank! And VLC won't open the .wtv file.

Comment: Puzzling. Can you post a sample .wtv file somewhere?

Comment: Sample file here:
http://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y1p3nxXn-CSngNIb6Dn49u55h-YkCA-hBmzWs8pExFbPz1VXkInUS6CAw53CCffZ0nb-TcQ4UATlF0R6hqBwtgO1A/BadAudioClip.wtv?download

Comment: Does my last edit help?

Comment: It lead me to the solution. Seems there's a tool called The Media Center Decoder Utility ( http://www.whittakermoore.com/mcdu.exe ). I used that to set the audio codec to AAC. Seems it's not suficient to just install the codec, it must be set at well.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: If you want to make another answer the refs the MC decoder utility, I'll upvote it and mark it as the answer

Comment: Thanks : I've corrected the answer to contain a direct reference to the utility. I think guarding the entire answer might be useful for others.